# Yii2 : How to change URL in Action Column Grid View?

Tags: url, gridview, yii2

I want to change url in action `view`, from view to `viewdaily`, `viewweekly` and `viewmonthly`, what should i do?

```
[
 'class'  => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 
],
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995310/change-the-button-action-in-gridview-based-on-a-model-attribute-value-yii2/30999037#30999037

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is not create/use ActionColumn, instead you can use raw-column and show there what  you want:

```
[
   'attribute' => 'some_title',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {                      
        return '<a href="'.$yourUrl .'">your Text</a>';
    },
],
```